# HTML href to a child element

Tags: jquery, html

There has to a dry way of doing this but I have not been able to find it.

```
<a href="image.jpg"> <!-- Don't repeat "image.jpg" -->
    <img src="image.jpg" /> <!-- HEY, you repeated "image.jpg" ! -->
</a>
```

Comment: Without Javascript?

Comment: Doesn't matter with or without. Just wanted a way to not have to repeat filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *DRY* solution is not feasible without javascript or jquery. Using jQuery:

```
 $("a").has("img").each(function(){
     $(this).find("img").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
 });
```

Comment: This works great and will save me a lot of extra work. Thanks @kad

Answer (score 1):

DRY shouldn't be taken to extremes, at times repeating code is at times unavoidable or impractical if you do A to B then A to C to B just to avoid a repeating code. HTML is not code that DRY can really apply to very well. There's no way of having 5 identical `<div>`s without repeating the `<div>` 4 more times unless you use JavaScript.

This Snippet demonstrates DRY with HTML.

> **Objective**
>
> Make a row of 3 identical images that go to the same location when clicked.

- **Typical Way**

  The top 3 images is the typical way repeating the markup of each `a > img` set.
- **DRY way**

  The bottom 3 images is actually one `background-image` repeated vertically with the `background-repeat` property with the value of `repeat-y`.

**SNIPPET**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none transparent;
}
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.pic {
  width: 610px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://imgh.us/Lenna.png) repeat-x;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Typical Way</h3>
<p>3 <code>&lt;img&gt;</code> and 3 <code>&lt;a&gt;</code>
</p>
<a href='http://imgh.us/Lenna.png'>
  <img src='http://imgh.us/Lenna.png'>
</a>
<a href='http://imgh.us/Lenna.png'>
  <img src='http://imgh.us/Lenna.png'>
</a>
<a href='http://imgh.us/Lenna.png'>
  <img src='http://imgh.us/Lenna.png'>
</a>


<h3>DRY way</h3>
<p>1 <code>&lt;img&gt;</code> and 1 <code>&lt;a&gt;</code>
</p>
<a href='http://imgh.us/Lenna.png'>
  <figure class='pic'></figure>
</a>
```